# How to sort a list of strings delimited by '.' with also numbers in the middle?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, split

I have a list of strings that contain commands separated by a dot `.` like this:

```
DeviceA.CommandA.1.Hello,
DeviceA.CommandA.2.Hello,
DeviceA.CommandA.11.Hello,
DeviceA.CommandA.3.Hello,
DeviceA.CommandB.1.Hello,
DeviceA.CommandB.1.Bye,
DeviceB.CommandB.What,
DeviceA.SubdeviceA.CommandB.1.Hello,
DeviceA.SubdeviceA.CommandB.2.Hello,
DeviceA.SubdeviceB.CommandA.1.What
```

And I would want to order them in natural order:

1. The order must prioritize by field index (e.g The commands that start with DeviceA will always go before DeviceB etc)
2. Order alphabetically the strings
3. When it finds a number sort numerically in ascending order

Therefore, the **sorted output** should be:

```
DeviceA.CommandA.1.Hello,
DeviceA.CommandA.2.Hello,
DeviceA.CommandA.3.Hello,
DeviceA.CommandA.11.Hello,
DeviceA.CommandB.1.Bye,
DeviceA.CommandB.1.Hello,
DeviceA.SubdeviceA.CommandB.1.Hello,
DeviceA.SubdeviceA.CommandB.2.Hello,
DeviceA.SubdeviceB.CommandA.What,
DeviceB.CommandB.What
```

Also note that the **length of the command fields is dynamic**, the number of fields separated by dot can be any size.

So far I tried this without luck (the numbers are order alphabetically, for example 11 goes before 5):

```
list = [
    "DeviceA.CommandA.1.Hello",
    "DeviceA.CommandA.2.Hello",
    "DeviceA.CommandA.11.Hello",
    "DeviceA.CommandA.3.Hello",
    "DeviceA.CommandB.1.Hello",
    "DeviceA.CommandB.1.Bye",
    "DeviceB.CommandB.What",
    "DeviceA.SubdeviceA.CommandB.1.Hello",
    "DeviceA.SubdeviceA.CommandB.2.Hello",
    "DeviceA.SubdeviceB.CommandA.1.What"
]

sorted_list = sorted(list, key=lambda x: x.split('.'))
```

**EDIT**: Corrected typo error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should get you going.

```
from pprint import pprint

data_list = [
    "DeviceA.CommandA.1.Hello",
    "DeviceA.CommandA.2.Hello",
    "DeviceA.CommandA.3.Hello",
    "DeviceA.CommandB.1.Hello",
    "DeviceA.CommandB.1.Bye",
    "DeviceB.CommandB.What",
    "DeviceA.SubdeviceA.CommandB.1.Hello",
    "DeviceA.SubdeviceA.CommandB.15.Hello",  # added test case to ensure numbers are sorted numerically
    "DeviceA.SubdeviceA.CommandB.2.Hello",
    "DeviceA.SubdeviceB.CommandA.1.What",
]


def get_sort_key(s):
    # Turning the pieces to integers would fail some comparisons (1 vs "What")
    # so instead pad them on the left to a suitably long string
    return [
        bit.rjust(30, "0") if bit.isdigit() else bit
        for bit in s.split(".")
    ]


# Note the key function must be passed as a kwarg.
sorted_list = sorted(data_list, key=get_sort_key)

pprint(sorted_list)
```

The output is

```
['DeviceA.CommandA.1.Hello',
 'DeviceA.CommandA.2.Hello',
 'DeviceA.CommandA.3.Hello',
 'DeviceA.CommandB.1.Bye',
 'DeviceA.CommandB.1.Hello',
 'DeviceA.SubdeviceA.CommandB.1.Hello',
 'DeviceA.SubdeviceA.CommandB.2.Hello',
 'DeviceA.SubdeviceA.CommandB.15.Hello',
 'DeviceA.SubdeviceB.CommandA.1.What',
 'DeviceB.CommandB.What']
```

Comment: Thanks it seems the correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

Specifying a `key` in `sorted` seems to achieve what you want:

```
import re

def my_key(s):
    n = re.search("\d+",s)
    return (s[:n.span()[0]], int(n[0])) if n else (s,) 

print(sorted(l, key = my_key))
```

**Output**:

```
['DeviceA.CommandA.1.Hello', 'DeviceA.CommandA.2.Hello', 'DeviceA.CommandA.3.Hello', 'DeviceA.CommandA.11.Hello', 'DeviceA.CommandB.1.Hello', 'DeviceA.CommandB.1.Bye', 'DeviceA.SubdeviceA.CommandB.1.Hello', 'DeviceA.SubdeviceA.CommandB.2.Hello', 'DeviceA.SubdeviceB.CommandA.1.What', 'DeviceB.CommandB.What']
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this. Here's one that doesn't rely on importation of any additional modules:

```
LOS = ['DeviceA.CommandA.1.Hello',
       'DeviceA.CommandA.2.Hello',
       'DeviceA.CommandA.11.Hello',
       'DeviceA.CommandA.3.Hello',
       'DeviceA.CommandB.1.Hello',
       'DeviceA.CommandB.1.Bye',
       'DeviceB.CommandB.What',
       'DeviceA.SubdeviceA.CommandB.1.Hello',
       'DeviceA.SubdeviceA.CommandB.2.Hello',
       'DeviceA.SubdeviceB.CommandA.1.What']


def func(s):
    tokens = s.split('.')
    for i, token in enumerate(tokens):
        try:
            v = int(token)
            return ('.'.join(tokens[0:i]), v)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return (s, 0)


print(sorted(LOS, key=func))
```